# UIActivity Subclass Mail

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller, uiactivity

I am using `UIActivityViewController` to share data from my app. I know how I can create a custom `UIActivity` subclass and include that on my share sheet.

However, is it possible to customise the system activities? For example, I want to send some data via an email. Can I customise the system one to take my data, subject etc?

I don't want to exclude `UIActivityTypeMail` and then just create a custom one, I want my data etc going through the system Mail activity.